# How to keep a unique container identifier in an auto scaling docker architecture after an auto-restart?

Tags: docker

My application includes several instances of the same micro-services with auto-restart set on. When an instance restarts, it has to perform some sanity checks and clean things when needed in the database, but only its own.

The solution I have used is to declare an environment variable in the docker file to differentiate the instances. Say I have two instances, docker-file-for-instance-1 contains:

```
ENV INSTANCE=1
```

and docker-file-for-instance-2 contains:

```
ENV INSTANCE=2
```

With this trick, the instance can after restart check the data of its own work, which is recorded in the database with the help of a column *instance* which takes the value of the environment variable INSTANCE.

But this scales badly.

- A first idea would be to have one single docker file for every instance, so without the INSTANCE environment variable. But then, how to distinguish what is written in the database by which instance ?
- A second idea would be to use an orchestrator that would manage the instance value in the docker file. I don't know these technologies yet. Is it possible ?

EDIT : adds on Tarun Lalwani solution below to check UUID behaviour with two containers

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Building Image"
docker build -t c1i . > /dev/null

echo "Killing existing container if any"
for c in c1 c2; do
  if [[ `docker ps --filter "name=$c" --format "{{.Names}}"` == $c ]]; then docker kill $c; docker rm $c; fi;
  echo "Starting container $c in background"
  docker run -d --name $c c1i > /dev/null
  docker ps -a
  echo "Restarting container $c"
  docker restart $c > /dev/null
  docker ps -a
done;

for c in c1 c2; do
  echo "Restarting container $c again"
  docker restart $c > /dev/null
  docker ps -a
done;

for c in c1 c2; do
  echo "Checking container $c logs"
  docker logs $c
done;

docker ps -a

for c in c1 c2; do
  echo "Checking container $c UUID"
  docker exec $c cat /etc/environment.container
done;

echo "Killing containers"
for c in c1 c2; do
  if [[ `docker ps --filter "name=$c" --format "{{.Names}}"` == $c ]]; then docker kill $c; docker rm $c; fi;
done;
```

**init.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

ENV_FILE=/etc/environment.container
#cat $ENV_FILE



if [ -f $ENV_FILE ]; then
   . $ENV_FILE
fi

if [ -z "${CONTAINER_UUID}" ]; then
   echo "Starting container for the first time"
   CONTAINER_UUID=$(uuidgen -r)
   echo "CONTAINER_UUID=$CONTAINER_UUID" >> $ENV_FILE
   echo "UUID of new container is $CONTAINER_UUID"
else
   CONTAINER_UUID=${CONTAINER_UUID}
   echo "Restarting container with $CONTAINER_UUID"
fi

echo "------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------"
exec tail -f /dev/null

exit 0
```

The dockerfile is the same.

Here is the console output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
Building Image
Killing existing container if any
Starting container c1 in background
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
1cd1b7961f5a        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   2 seconds ago       Up Less than a second                       c1
Restarting container c1
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
1cd1b7961f5a        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   14 seconds ago      Up Less than a second                       c1
Starting container c2 in background
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
f8654d93936e        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   2 seconds ago       Up Less than a second                       c2
1cd1b7961f5a        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   16 seconds ago      Up 2 seconds                                c1
Restarting container c2
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
f8654d93936e        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   15 seconds ago      Up Less than a second                       c2
1cd1b7961f5a        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   29 seconds ago      Up 14 seconds                               c1
Restarting container c1 again
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
f8654d93936e        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   27 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds                               c2
1cd1b7961f5a        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   41 seconds ago      Up Less than a second                       c1
Restarting container c2 again
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
f8654d93936e        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   39 seconds ago      Up Less than a second                       c2
1cd1b7961f5a        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   53 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds                               c1
Checking container c1 logs
Starting container for the first time
UUID of new container is 432bfc77-e186-4ca2-bb9a-450b370d05a3
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
Restarting container with 432bfc77-e186-4ca2-bb9a-450b370d05a3
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
Restarting container with 432bfc77-e186-4ca2-bb9a-450b370d05a3
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
Checking container c2 logs
Starting container for the first time
UUID of new container is 9eae8f6c-c332-422a-a35a-6ec1d59b6e6c
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
Restarting container with 9eae8f6c-c332-422a-a35a-6ec1d59b6e6c
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
Restarting container with 9eae8f6c-c332-422a-a35a-6ec1d59b6e6c
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
f8654d93936e        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   39 seconds ago      Up Less than a second                       c2
1cd1b7961f5a        c1i                 "/bin/sh -c /init.sh"   53 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds                               c1
Checking container c1 UUID
CONTAINER_UUID=432bfc77-e186-4ca2-bb9a-450b370d05a3
Checking container c2 UUID
CONTAINER_UUID=9eae8f6c-c332-422a-a35a-6ec1d59b6e6c
Killing containers
```

I have tried 2 other solutions but not managed to make them work:

**Dockerfile (alternative 1 - does not work)**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install uuid-runtime -y
COPY ./init2.sh /etc/init.d/init.sh
CMD chmod a+x /etc/init.d/init.sh
```

**Dockerfile (alternative 2 - does not work)**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install uuid-runtime -y
COPY ./init.sh /etc/rc.local
CMD chmod a+x /etc/rc.local
```

**init2.sh (alternative - does not work)**

```
#! /bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin
do_start () {
    ENV_FILE=/etc/environment.container
    echo "exec init.sh on container :"
    cat $ENV_FILE   
    if [ -f $ENV_FILE ]; then
       . $ENV_FILE
    fi    
    if [ -z "${CONTAINER_UUID}" ]; then
       echo "Starting container for the first time"
       CONTAINER_UUID=$(uuidgen -r)
       echo "CONTAINER_UUID=$CONTAINER_UUID" >> $ENV_FILE
       echo "UUID of new container is $CONTAINER_UUID"
    else
       CONTAINER_UUID=${CONTAINER_UUID}
       echo "Restarting container with $CONTAINER_UUID"
    fi    
    echo "------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------"
    #exec tail -f /dev/null
}

do_status () {
}    
case "$1" in
  start|"")
    do_start
    ;;
  restart|reload|force-reload|stop|status)
    # No-op
    ;;
  *)
    ;;
esac    
exit 0
```

What am I doing wrong here please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would not generate container ID outside the container. I would generate it from inside the container only.

I worked out a sample which works great.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install uuid-runtime -y
COPY ./init.sh /init.sh
CMD /init.sh
```

**init.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

ENV_FILE=/etc/environment.container
cat $ENV_FILE

if [ -f $ENV_FILE ]; then
   . $ENV_FILE
fi

if [ -z "${CONTAINER_UUID}" ]; then
   echo "Starting container for the first time"
   CONTAINER_UUID=$(uuidgen -r)
   echo "CONTAINER_UUID=$CONTAINER_UUID" >> $ENV_FILE
   echo "UUID of new container is $CONTAINER_UUID"
else
   CONTAINER_UUID=${CONTAINER_UUID}
   echo "Restarting container with $CONTAINER_UUID"
fi

echo "------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------"
exec tail -f /dev/null
```

Then created a test.sh to see the functionality

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Building Image"
docker build -t c1i . > /dev/null

echo "Killing existing container if any"
docker kill c1 > /dev/null
docker rm c1 > /dev/null

echo "Starting container in background"
docker run -d --name c1 c1i > /dev/null

echo "Restarting container"
docker restart c1 > /dev/null

echo "Restarting container again"
docker restart c1 > /dev/null

echo "Checking container logs"
docker logs c1
```

The output of above test is as below

```
Building Image
Killing existing container if any
Starting container in background
Restarting container
Restarting container again
Checking container logs
Starting container for the first time
UUID of new container is 23615a43-3b59-4369-82c7-0202ad227403
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
cat: /etc/environment.container: No such file or directory
CONTAINER_UUID=23615a43-3b59-4369-82c7-0202ad227403
Restarting container with 23615a43-3b59-4369-82c7-0202ad227403
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
CONTAINER_UUID=23615a43-3b59-4369-82c7-0202ad227403
Restarting container with 23615a43-3b59-4369-82c7-0202ad227403
------------------ END OF CONTAINER INIT ----------------
```

As you can see the environment variable is always unique as it is UUID based and it is persisted after restart of the same container

Comment: Why does it work because init.sh is executed before the creation of the image, so I expected both containers to have the same UUID ?

Comment: Because restart will still persists the top R/W layer of the container

Comment: In the case of large scale deployment where a server is jeopardized, sanity checks and cleaning shall be perform by another mean since the UUID is lost with the container. One idea would be to store the environment.container into a NAS and have a service that checks older ones than containers

Comment: Yes, or you can even log the last reporting time of every container. The ones which don't report for long can be presumed dead and clean up initiated.

Comment: ok, but I still not understand. Both containers are built on an image where the file `environment.container` had already been built once and only once in the image, what should make the UUID the same for all containers ?

Comment: Each container will generate a UUID when it starts. It will remain with the container until it is stopped or killed. It will be able to retain UUID if it is restarted. If a new container is started instead of it, then that will generated a new UUID for itself

Comment: Thank you very much. But in my understanding of containers, the layers composing the image are RO. When the container is created from the image, a RW layer is added. As the Dockerfile is used to build the image, and as the call to init.sh is used inside the image build with CMD, the UUID is written RO inside the image, not in the container RW layer. Of course, you are right since your solution works, but my understanding is puzzled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153533/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-lalebarde).

Comment: I just add here the root cause of why it works: [Each layer except the very last one is read-only](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/)